# Structures not working correctly?

Tags: c++

```
Fraction AddFractions(const Fraction& frac1, const Fraction& frac2)
{
    Fraction frac3;

    if (frac1.denom == frac2.denom)
    {
        frac3.num = frac1.num + frac2.num;
        frac3.denom = frac1.denom;          
    }
    else
    {
        frac3.denom = (frac1.denom * frac2.denom);
        frac3.num = (frac1.num * frac2.denom) + (frac2.num * frac1.denom);          
    }
    return frac3;
}
```

This is my prototype and there is a structure defined as `Fraction` with `int num` and `int denom` when I call the function it just gives me back garbage? I don't know what's wrong with it.  Please help. =(

```
    cout << "Please enter two Fractions" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    GetFraction(frac1); 
    cout << "Your fisrt fraction is: ";
    PrintFraction(frac1);
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    GetFraction(frac2);
    cout << "Your second fraction is: ";
    PrintFraction(frac2);
    cout << endl;


    do
    {
        choice1 = MathMenu();
        if (choice1 == ErrorOpt)
        {
            cout << "There was an error with what you have entered" << endl;
        }
        else if(choice1 != QuitOpt)
        {

            // do the math options 
            switch (choice1)
            {
            case AddOpt:
                AddFractions(frac1, frac2);
                break;
            case SubtractOpt:
                SubtractFractions(frac1, frac2);
                break;
            case MultiplyOpt:
                MultiplyFractions(frac1, frac2);
                break;
            case DivideOpt:
                DivideFractions(frac1, frac2);
                break;
            }
            //print the results 
            PrintFraction(frac1);
            PrintMathOption(choice1);
            PrintFraction(frac2);
            cout << " = ";
            Standardize(frac3);
            Reduce(frac3);
            PrintFraction(frac3);
            cout << endl;
            Pause();
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you have an uninitialized stack variable or something along those lines.  Can you post the code where you define your two fractions and call this function?

Comment: Programming language feature X is broken! No, it probably isn't.

Comment: Do you have copy ctor and assignment operator defined ? Also how are you calling AddFractions(...) ? Can we see code ?

Comment: If it is not an exercise you might benefit from using existing implementations e.g., Boost.Rational http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/rational/index.html

Answer (score 4):

You should assign `frac3` e.g.:

```
frac3 = AddFractions(frac1, frac2);
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter: the result of the function can be safely ignored, but printing an uninitialized variable may produce garbage.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that he had a variable named `frac3` at all. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell from your code; there is no variable `frac3` in the scope of:

```
        Standardize(frac3);
        Reduce(frac3);
        PrintFraction(frac3);
```

And your math functions are being called but you are not capturing the returns.